# What is the difference between class_name and inverse_class_name in Mongoid?

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3

What is the difference between class_name and inverse_class_name in Mongoid?

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you a clear understanding of the difference:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :items
end

class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :order
end

item = Item.new
order = Order.create({ items: [ item ] })

puts order.items.metadata.class_name
# => Item

puts order.items.metadata.inverse_class_name
# => Order
```

That is, `class_name` is the referrer class of a relation, while `inverse_class_name` is the referee class of the relation.